# Output going to terminal instead of html doc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

Ok, so I just picked up ruby yesterday..The app I made tracks tweets and stores them in an array, and should output to webpage but I don't know the proper syntax

Output is just running in the terminal. 
html

```
<h1>Posts#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/posts/index.html.erb</p>
<%= @a %>
```

ruby

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY = ""
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
  TWITTER_OATH_TOKEN = ""
  TWITTER_OATH_TOKEN_SECRET = ""
  def index
    @a = Array.new(500)

    TweetStream.configure do |config|
       config.consumer_key = TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY
       config.consumer_secret = TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET
       config.oauth_token = TWITTER_OATH_TOKEN
       config.oauth_token_secret = TWITTER_OATH_TOKEN_SECRET
     end
     i = 0
     TweetStream.track('weed') do |status|

     temp = status.text

     if(temp.include? "http")
          a[i] = status.text
          puts "#{status.text}"
          i = i+1
          end
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: show some code please?

Comment: I hope those keys aren't real...

Comment: awesome, thanks, i reset access btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a LOT that I'd do differently, but using your code:

Change `a[i]` in your view to `@a[i]`...

You could do something like this:

```
<% @a.each do |tweet| %>
  <div class="tweet">
    <%= tweet %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And style the `<div>` appropriately.  Or use `<ul>` and `<li>` if it works better for you.

Comment: i think i need a timer or something because i cant even get the page to load, its pulling feed constantly

Comment: I'd start with something a bit simpler.  Watch Ryan's wonderful RoR videos at [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com) for some great tutorials.